# Woocommerce Login Custome API Endpoint

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing an app using woocommerece store and using the Woocommerce REST API for Fetching the Products and Order details, but now I am facing the problem in login because Woocommerce didn't provide this type of API.
So I am creating a custom endpoint and trying this but I am getting the error 404, no rest route available.

Here is my custome end point which i registered.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
 register_rest_route( 'wc/v2', '/login/)', array(
 'methods' => 'POST',
 'callback'=> 'my_awesome_func',
 'args' => array(
 ), 
 ) );
} );
```

Here is the login of Login but i think i am doing anything wrong at someplace so please check and help me .

```
function my_awesome_func( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
global $wpdb;
$username = $request['email'];
$password = $request['password'];
$db = new DbOperation();
    $response = array();    
    $login_data = array();
    $login_data['user_login'] = $username;
    $login_data['user_password'] = $password;
    $results = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT ID FROM rd_users WHERE user_email='".$username."'");
    $activation_id = $results->ID;
    $activation_key =  get_user_meta( $activation_id, 'has_to_be_activated', true );
    if($activation_key != false ){
       $results = 2;//if activation key exists than show the error
    }
     else{
            $user_verify = wp_signon( $login_data, false ); 
            if ( is_wp_error($user_verify) ) 
            {
              $results = 0; //show invalid username and password.
            }
             else {    
               $results = 1; //login success.
            }
    }
    if ($results== 1) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($student[0]->ID);
    $response['id'] = $user_info->ID;
    $response['name'] = $user_info->display_name;
    $response['fname'] = $user_info->first_name;
    $response['lname'] = $user_info->last_name;
    $response['email'] = $user_info->user_email;
    $response['status'] = 1;
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response['message'] = "You have successfully Logedin!";
} else {
    if($results == 0){
    $response['status'] = 0;
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid username or password";
    }
    else{
        $response['status'] = 2;
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response['message'] ="Your account has not been activated yet.
         To activate it check your email and clik on the activation link.";
        }
}
return  $response;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

See what i have found,
used https authentication. In postman, instead of using oAuth1.0 as the authentication, use Basic authentication and pass consumer key as the username. And the password should be consumer secret.

I hope that would work.

Comment: he asked a pretty straight forward question, how to login with customer using woocommerce API. Your answer says nothing at all.